# Very simple formula done in a better way ? :)

Tags: calculus

I've got this and I am not happy with it:

```
R= A / (A - DIFF)
if (R > 1) R = 1/R
PERCENTAGE = R * 100
```

A: positive number
DIFF: a positive number in between 0 and A

I'm just not used to math, I bet a more math-used mind can give me a one-liner in a second ?

I calculate the precision/error of a value in percent.
A is the value, DIFF is the error from my samples.

I want to get rid of the "IF" so it's a proper formula and not a hackish 3 liner.

Comment: Here’s a [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @John Don't worry about the downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are `R` and `RATIO` the same? I'll assume so. So if `DIFF` is between zero and `A`, then `RATIO` will always be greater than one (so the `if` condition will always be true). Just do instead

```
 PERCENTAGE = 100* ((A-DIFF) / A)
```